# Want to Display latest node on the basis of taxonomy term

Tags: views

Actually I want to display latest node on the basis of taxonomy term..
Suppose 
I created a vocabulary called event.
With field

```
1. Term name
2. Description
3. Image
Now I have a node with following field
1. Title
2. Term reference field reffering event 
3. Event date.
```

Now I want to display exactly 1 latest node basis of term name.. 
Suppose I have 3 term so I want to display latest 1 node for each term.. using view.

Please help me on that thank you..

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you'll want to create a View for your event nodes, and then add a relationship to the "Event category" or whatever your term reference field is called on the node. You should then be able to add a sort by Event date descending, and a filter for the "Term name" that should be available through the relationship you've added. You could limit your results to 1 node only in the pager settings in Views. Then you should have the latest event for a specific term.

Comment: when you are doing results to 1 node only in the pager settings in Views it will display only one result from all of the content